Facturacion con Fel
estoy usando fel para hacer el timbrado, el problema esta en que necesito pasarle un xml para hacer el timbrado, entonces yo necesito crear el xml. estoy usando una clase que se llama SelloDital para generar el sello
SelloDigital oSelloDigital = new SelloDigital();
        oComprobante.Certificado = oSelloDigital.Certificado(pathCer);
        oComprobante.Sello = oSelloDigital.Sellar(cadenaOriginal, pathKey, clavePrivada);

el problema es que cuando lo uso con CSD diferentes si me genera el xml, pero cuando quiero usar los sellos proporcionados por fel, no me deja generar el sello, por ende no puedo generar el xml y no puedo timbrar. estoy trabajando con.NET

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No deberias preguntar todas esas cosas a quienes te dieron esas librerias???
